# How to use $this->autoRender = false in cakephp 3.6.10?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to display the test data on the screen by running function test() in the pagesController. Used $this->autoRender = false for it, but it is still giving me error:

[image]

Please help me out. I think some version problem is there, but I can't figure it out. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cakephp by default takes Pages controller's display actions as a home page. display function manages pages and subpages itself that is why you are getting error. Either you can change your default home page  in your `/config/routes.php`

```
 $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);
```

**OR**

define your test action in some other controller.

**OR**

Remove code from display action

```
class PagesController {
    function display()
    {
        // default controller code here
        // your custom code here
    }
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: thanx brother.. I was not knowing that display function was the actual problem. Your first suggestion helped me to get the output. Kudos bro!